# nginx rewrite with try_files 403

Tags: nginx

I have a webserver with /usercp/ and usercp.php. I'm using tryfiles and re-write to see if file.php exists do file, otherwise goto /file/ (in my case file = usercp)

Here is my nginx conf.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @extension-php;
}

location @extension-php {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.php last;
}
```

This also makes site.com/usercp/ give a 403 error. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, but /usercp/.php does not exist. You should consider the possibility of a trailing slash. Try this instead `rewrite ^(.*)/?$ $1.php last;`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are prioritizing the folder indexing over the php file if you want the opposite I recommend not to use the `autoindex on` because it exposes the contents of your folder and swap the last 2 items in the try_files, try this

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.php $uri/;
}
```

**PS:** `$uri/` will always return 403 if it doesn't contain the index file specified in `index` because by default it forbids folder listing, you should either put the index file if that's what you intend to do, or just remove the whole `$uri/` from the `try_files` so that it would return `404` instead of `403`

Answer (score 1):

http://nginx.org/r/try_files

What it does is simply checks the existence of files, and then serves the file that exists.

You claim `/usercp/` exists.  As such, that's what it'll try to serve.  But you probably don't have `autoindex on`, hence, directory listing is disallowed — `403 Forbidden`.